# Meidawiki: Get user contribution word-count

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any extension or any other option available in mediawiki to get the word-count of the contribution/edit by a user?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet; but you can patch https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Contribution_Scores to do this calculation as well, diffing rev_len values (see manual:revision_table for docs).

Comment: How do I do that?